# Existence of an open set with specific properties

Tags: affine-geometry, character-sheaves

I am currently reading Gerard Laumon's *Faisceaux caractères*, which details various constructions and properties of character sheaves on a connected reductive group $G$ over $\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p$. At a certain point, he makes the following assertion:

**Claim:** Let $s \in G$ be semisimple. There exists an open neighbourhood $\mathcal{U} \subseteq Z^0_G(s)$ of the identity $e$ such that

1. For every $x \in Z^0_G(s)$, $x\mathcal{U}x^{-1} = \mathcal{U}$.
2. Given $x \in Z^0_G(s)$ with Jordan decomposition $x=x_s x_u$, we have
   $$ x \in \mathcal{U} \Leftrightarrow x_s \in \mathcal{U}. $$
3. Given $x \in \mathcal{U}$ and $g \in G$ such that $g^{-1}sxg \in B$ (resp. $T$), we have both $g^{-1}sg \in B$ (resp. $T$) and $g^{-1}x_sg \in B$ (resp. $T$).

In the last condition, $B$ and $T \subseteq B$ are a Borel subgroup and maximal torus respectively.

Laumon does not give a construction of such an open neighbourhood, so I have been trying to find one myself. My first observation is that if $x$ is unipotent then $x_s = e \in \mathcal{U}$, so condition 2 implies $x \in \mathcal{U}$. We might therefore take an open neighbourhood of the unipotent elements in $Z^0_G(s)$, and then also include all of the conjugates in $Z^0_G(s)$ so that condition 1 is satisfied.

My problem is that I don't have any intuition for condition 3, so I don't know how to modify this construction to satisfy all three simultaneously.

**Question:** How does one construct such a neighbourhood?

Perhaps more importantly, can anyone offer intuition for condition 3?